# How to Make R Plotly Grouped Bar Plot (with Data Labels)?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a grouped bar plot with plotly in R. I can create what I want with ggplot but I can't use ggplotly because of the issue where it does not display negative numbers correctly (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560). I have two questions that I am hoping you can help with:

1. How do I make it so that the bars that are in the same group are side by side? For example, in the plot below the Age bars (Young, Middle, and Old) are not touching even though those bars are all part of the Age group.
2. Also, how can I have each annotation horizontally centered over the bar it is associated with? For example, the age labels are currently centered over the x axis label Age rather than over their respective bars. If this is not possible having the annotation underneath the x axis in some way would also work.

Here's my code so far:

```
# Create example data
example_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 9, 3))
names(example_data) <- c("group", "subgroup", "value")
example_data$group <- c("Gender", "Gender", "Race", "Race", "Race", "Age", "Age", "Age", "Human")
example_data$subgroup <- c("Female", "Male", "Asian", "Black", "White", "Young", "Middle", "Old", "Yes")
example_data$value <- c(11, 14, 72, 12, 82, 22, 30, 4, 5)

# Create chart
p <- plot_ly(
  data = example_data,
  x = ~group,
  y = ~value,
  color = ~subgroup,
  type = "bar"
) %>%
  layout(
    # xaxis = list(type="category"), # Doesn't seem to do anything
    # barmode = "group", # Doesn't seem to do anything
    showlegend = FALSE
) %>%
add_annotations(text = ~subgroup,
                x = ~group,
                y = ~value / 2, # Center vertically on the bar
                # xref = "x", # Doesn't seem to do anything
                # yref = "y", # Doesn't seem to do anything
                # xanchor = 'center', # Doesn't seem to do anything
                # yanchor = 'bottom', # Doesn't seem to do anything
                showarrow = FALSE)

p
```

[image: plotly grouped bar plot example]

Comment: Why you want `plot_ly()` why not `geom_bar()`?

Comment: I need to use plotly because the plot is part of a Shiny dashboard. Plotly is needed so that the user can use the plotly features like downloading a png of the plot, zooming, and selecting/deselecting groups.

Comment: What about `gvis`?

Comment: Think about `add_trace` I could make the bars to line up as you want by `add_trace` but couldn't get the texts correctly. p.s. used `melt` and `dcast` to pivot the data.frame.

Comment: @JustinMeyer were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If still interested, I found such parameters: xanchor='right', xshift=-10 (move it left, -10 relates to 10 pixels) the same for move label right ->xanchor='left', xshift=10

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/annotations/attributes.js

but annotations need to be separated:
add_annotations(text = Male, xshift=-10....
add_annotations(text = Female, xshift=10....